# Filtrar elementos de un objeto en JavaScript de acuerdo a una condicion

Tags: filtro

Se crea la función llamada productosBaratos que reciba un arreglo de objetos (que representan productos) y se debe retornar un nuevo arreglo con los nombres de los productos cuyo precio esté entre 5 y 10:

```
function productosBaratos(prods){
  for (let elemento of prods){
   if(elemento.precio >= 5 && elemento.precio <= 10){
     console.log([elemento.nombre])
     }
  }
}
        
//codigo de prueba
let prods = [
  { nombre: "Arroz", precio: 5 },
  { nombre: "Pan", precio: 3 },
  { nombre: "Tomate", precio: 8 },
  { nombre: "Leche", precio: 15 }
];
        
//resultado esperado
console.log(productosBaratos(prods)); // ["Arroz", "Tomate"]
```

Con el codigo que realice creo es dos arreglos que cumplen la condición:

["Arroz"]

["Tomate"]

Answer (score 0):

con la funcion filter es sencillo,
te dejo un ejemplo solo adaptalo a tu codigo

```js
//codigo de prueba
let prods = [
  { nombre: "Arroz", precio: 5 },
  { nombre: "Pan", precio: 3 },
  { nombre: "Tomate", precio: 8 },
  { nombre: "Leche", precio: 15 }
];
const result = prods.filter(prod => prod.precio < 10);
console.log(result)
```